# WebAPI2 : [DELETE] Method not allowed in CODE but in Fiddler it is working

Tags: c#, httpclient, webapi2

I tested my WebAPI2 (DELETE) in Fiddler and it is working fine but in my code had an error of Method not Allowed.

This is my Code :

```
    public async Task<bool> deleteUser(int id)
    {
        string URI = "http://api.danubeco.com/api/userapps";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {   
            var response = await client.DeleteAsync(String.Format("{0}/{1}", URI, id));

            var myobject = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Convert.ToBoolean(myobject);
        }            
    }
```

---

```
    // DELETE: api/userapps/5        
    [ResponseType(typeof(userapp))]
    public IHttpActionResult Deleteuserapp(int id)
    {
        userapp userapp = db.userapps.Find(id);
        if (userapp == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.userapps.Remove(userapp);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(userapp);
    }
```

Comment: Did you capture the request created by this code and compare it to the request you created in fiddler?  I bet there's something different.. :)

Comment: @CodingGorilla in Fiddler i successfully delete a user using the same method but in code it response a Method not Allowed.

Comment: I understand that, but did you look at headers of the requests, I suspect you're missing a header that it wants.

Comment: Are you using attribute based routing? If so, do you have the [HttpDelete] attribute on the method?

Comment: Make sure you have a route in your WebApiConfig.cs that has action = "Delete" for your controller, since you don't appear to be using attribute based routing.

Comment: I attached the Delete method of WebAPI.

Comment: @CodingGorilla HTTP/1.1 200 OK - Header Response

Comment: @Kevin what do you mean?

Comment: @BillSambrone nope. aint using that because codes automatic generated by action w/ EF

Comment: In your App_Start folder there should be a file named WebApiConfig.cs where you can define the routes for your controllers. Since I don't see any HTTP action attributes in your code I was assuming you are configuring your routes there.

Comment: @Kevin i only have 2 Config Routes. 

1. `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"` and 2. `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{userid}/{password}"`

Comment: `{StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
  Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2016 18:21:45 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 1015
  Allow: GET
  Allow: HEAD
  Allow: OPTIONS
  Allow: TRACE
  Content-Type: text/html
}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "YourControllerApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "YourControler", action = "Delete", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Of course you'll need to replace "YourController with the name of your controller class, and you may need to tweak the routeTemplate (this one assumes you'll call YourURL/api/YourController.

Comment: The only other place I know of where the allowed HTTP verbs are defined is in the Web.config under system.WebServer/handlers where it defines which ExtensionlessUrlHandler(s) to use. But those should have been setup when you created your WebApi project.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if this is a good practice but i modified the code like this.

```
    // DELETE: api/userapps/5   
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/userapps/deluser/{id}")]
    [ActionName("deluser")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(bool))]
    public bool Deleteuserapp(int id)
    {
        userapp userapp = db.userapps.Find(id);
        if (userapp == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        db.userapps.Remove(userapp);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

---

```
    var response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format("{0}/{1}", URI,
```

---

and used GetAsync rather than DeleteAsync.